Apportionment of variation
I have a dataset of hundereds of thousands of websites (categorical) with their CO2 emissions per request (quantitative) along with the data centre they're hosted in (categorical), and whether those data centres use renewable energy or not (categorical: true or false).
I'm trying to determine/apportion variability in CO2 emissions to website design (variability across websites) and to whether they're hosted at a renewable using data centre.
Intuitively, I tried calculating the variances across the whole data set (variance between websites) and the variance between websites within each data centres and then the variance between those variances. That strikes me as the wrong thing to do though. I strongly suspect there is unaccounted for interaction, and also a variance of variance just strikes me as fishy.
My next thought was to try an ANOVA, but an ANOVA doesn't apportion variance AFAIK. Specifically, I'm not interested in whether the two variances are significantly different, but what they actually are, and how they compare to each other as contributions to total variance.
There are some other things I've been reading up on in Wikipedia, such as Coefficient of variation and Quartile coefficient of dispersion and also Cramer's V. All three of these techniques/approaches sound like they might be able to answer my question, but I'm not sure which one is the right approach if any?
How do I apportion contribution to variability to website vs renewable data centre?

Hi! I'm not sure what you mean by "apportion variance". In any case Cramér's V is certainly inadequate for what you're trying to do, as it is a measure of association between two categorical variables, and your variable of interest (CO2 emissions) doesn't sound categorical at all. I'd suggest that you change the tags of your question accordingly, and maybe add the tags [tag:variance], [tag:anova], and [tag:estimators] to it, so people following those tags will be much more likely to see your question.

I'm trying to determine how much of the total variance in carbon emissions is affected by data centre choice, vs website design choice.
